# Adding Rows in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I have a DGV that would change in columns, how would i modify the code to dynamically add all the cells what are present in the row, instead of hardcoding each cell - i could see a problem if i added 31 cells and then a month with 28 would throw an error. I'd miss the first column becuase thats a name, but all the rest are numbers.

```
For Each SelectedRow as DataGridViewRow in dgv_service_centers.SelectedRows()
Total = SelectedRow.Cells(1).value + SelectedRow.Cells(2).value + SelectedRow Cells(3).value
Next
```

Cheers,
Pete

Comment: Perhaps a DataExpression to sum 3 columns could be useful if you are using a datatable bound to the DGV. What is the ultimate purpose of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ is your friend in this case.

```
Dim sum = dgv_service_centers.SelectedRows.
                              Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().
                              Sum(Function(row) row.Cells.
                                                    Cast(Of DataGridViewCell)().
                                                    Sum(Function(cell) CInt(cell.Value)))
```

The inner expression sums the `Integer` values from each cell in the current row and the outer expression sums all those sums for the selected rows. If the values are some type other than `Integer`, replace the `Cint` as appropriate.